# Изменение размера QWebView

Tags: python, webview, qt, pyqt4

Каким образом можно расширить виджет QWebView на всё окно приложения, чтобы полностью убрать серую рамку?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вижу два варианта действий:

- Если окно создано в дизайнере форм и используется менеджер компоновки, то можно настроить его отступы:

[image]

- Если интерфейс создаётся вручную и вы используете класс главного окна QMainWindow, то с помощью метода setCentralWidget можно установить ваш QWebView как главный виджет.

Comment: @mks, интересует программное изменение этого свойства. 
Попробовал в дизайнере - Layout не отображается в свойствах, есть только layoutDirection.

Comment: Приведите исходник, как вы получаете ваше окно. У QMainWindow есть метод setCentralWidget. Если вы в него передадите ваш QWebView, то он отобразится без рамки.  
Не заметил, что у вас python, но суть от этого не должна поменяться.

Comment: @mks, спасибо, попробовал через QMainWindow - всё работает. Реализовывал через QWidget: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8493b9198684d3546f76 
Так понимаю, особой разницы в использовании нет.

Comment: Обновил ответ.